# What is Aya Glenmiir's "small, furry creature"?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

In the Adventurer's League adventure **Suits of the Mists** a character is introduced to the party:

> One of the patrons of the inn, an elf who displays the trappings of an arcanist and seems to be enjoying the company of the small, furry creature perched on her shoulder, asks to speak to you.

One of my players asked what it was, I told him it looked like a flying guinea pig and we moved on.

Is there any more detail on what this creature is?

Comment: ... when in doubt about small furry creatures, reply "miniature giant space hamster".

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - since this is a DND campaign, "space hamster" seems anachronistic. "Winged vorpal hamster" seems more fitting. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis (In-joke Alert: ["In the *Baldur's Gate* role-playing video game, the NPC Minsc has a pet 'miniature giant space hamster', which is the size of a normal hamster, called Boo."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsters_of_Spelljammer))

Comment: "Go for the eyes Boo! Go for the eyes!"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**A Monkey**

Part of Aya's description in *The Scroll Thief* (DDEX1-6 pg. 9):

> "Perched on the elf's shoulder is a small, grey-furred monkey."